Problema al recuperar Value Objects como nulos en modelo DDD con Entity Framework
Resumen del problema
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que implementa Domain-Driven Design (DDD) utilizando Value Objects en mis entidades. Hasta ahora, he logrado guardar correctamente los datos en la base de datos, pero al intentar recuperarlos, los Value Objects se devuelven como null, a pesar de que los datos existen.
Contexto del modelo
He definido una clase Person que contiene varios Value Objects, como AddressObjectValue y IdentificationObjectValue. A continuación, presento el código relevante de mi configuración y clases:
public class PersonConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasConversion(personId => personId.Id, personId => PersonId.Create());

        builder.Property(e => e.FirstName).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.LastName).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.Birthday).IsRequired();
        
        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Address, builder => { 
            builder.Property(a=> a.Street).HasColumnName("Address");
            builder.Property(a => a.Province).HasColumnName("Province");
            builder.Property(a => a.Country).HasColumnName("Country");
            builder.Property(a => a.City).HasColumnName("City");
        });
        builder.OwnsOne(e=> e.Identification, builder => 
        {
            builder.Property(i => i.IdentificationType).HasColumnName("IdentificationType");
            builder.Property(i => i.IdentificationNumber).HasColumnName("IdentificationNumber");
        });

    }
}

public abstract class BaseObjectValue
{
    protected abstract IEnumerable<object?> GetEqualityComponents();

    protected static bool EqualOperator(BaseObjectValue? left, BaseObjectValue? right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, objB: null) ^ ReferenceEquals(right, objB: null)) return false;

        return ReferenceEquals(left, objB: null) || left.Equals(right);
    }

    protected static bool NotEqualOperator(BaseObjectValue left, BaseObjectValue right)
    {
        return !(EqualOperator(left, right));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

        var other = (BaseObjectValue)obj;

        return this.GetEqualityComponents().SequenceEqual(other.GetEqualityComponents());
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetEqualityComponents()
              .Select(x => x != null
                               ? x.GetHashCode()
                               : 0)
              .Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y);
    }
}

public class AddressObjectValue : BaseObjectValue
{
    public string Country { init; get; } = null!;
    public string Province { init; get; } = null!;
    public string City { init; get; } = null!;
    public string Street { init; get; } = null!;

    private AddressObjectValue(string country, string province, string city, string street) 
        => (Country, Province, City, Street) = (country, province, city, street);

    public static AddressObjectValue Create(string country, string province, string city, string street)
        => new AddressObjectValue(country, province, city, street);

    protected override IEnumerable<object?> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Country;
        yield return Province;
        yield return City;
        yield return Street;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public PersonId Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateOnly Birthday { get; set; }

    public AddressObjectValue Address { get; set; } = null!;
    public IdentificationObjectValue Identification { get; set; } = null!;

}

Consulta y mensaje de error
Los nulos son Address e Identification

Lo demás lo trae ok

Problema
Al realizar una consulta para recuperar una instancia de Person, encuentro que los campos de los Value Objects (Address y Identification) se están devolviendo como null, aunque sé que los datos están presentes en la base de datos. He revisado la configuración del mapeo y no he encontrado errores evidentes.
Intentos de solución
Verifiqué que los datos existan efectivamente en la base de datos.
Revisé la configuración de OwnsOne en el mapeo de Entity Framework.
Me aseguré de que los constructores de los Value Objects estén correctamente definidos y que no haya errores de inicialización.
Pregunta
¿Por qué los Value Objects se están devolviendo como null al recuperar la entidad y cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

A AddressObjectValue le faltará un constructor vacio?? Por otro lado, si lo que tú quieres es poder comparar 2 objetos según sus propiedades, es decir que sean iguales cuando Country, Province, City, Street son iguales, te recomiendo utilizar record en lugar de class

Ahí hice lo que sugeriste del constructor vacío y no funcionó :( Curiosamente el campo Id lo mapea pero porque le pase un HasConversion. Y lo de record, decis de aplicarlo tanto a entidad como a OV?

Añado que hice lo de usar Record, y tampoco funcionó o cambio en algo el resultado

Edita tu pregunta y agrega la consulta que no recupera los datos que necesitas

listoo, ya lo agregué
